# How to typeset pseudo code in functional style (ML)?

Tags: algorithms

I'm a LaTeX noob. I want to write pseudo code in functional style as in the picture. [image]

```latex
\[

Weaken(c, A) = \\
\indent \indent  & \text{match $c$ with} \\ 
\indent \indent  & \mid \Gamma \vdash A \to B \\ 
\indent \indent  & \mid \Gamma \vdash C \to D 

\]
```

The above code gives the following output:

[image]

I don't want you guys to replicate the first image. I just want a template like in the code. I want to know if there is some standard package that simplifies all this. For instance, I don't want to write \mid and \indent all the time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Please add a minimal working example (MWE) with your best attempt to obtain the desired output, so other can modify to show you the alternatives without having to star from the scratch.

Comment: Hi, I don't want you to replicate all the math stuff. I know how to do that. I was just wondering if there is some standard package to write pseudo code in FP style.

Comment: You might try `minted`.

Comment: @Davislor, how do I put the math stuff inside minted?

Comment: You might also take a look at the various "algorithm" packages.  There are several on CTAN.